# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ADMIN' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql like below. Home hints:

Results in **K** table (from WITH) gives number codes of specified range (ex.: 1-90).

The **main select part** works fine until I use

```
sum(F._IsInIntersection) [CountIntersection]
```

It causes error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ADMIN' to data type int.

If I comment this line, it is OK.

I do not know, why this error occurs the line with `SUM()` contains only int values. No `ADMIN` value (as mentioned in the error) exists anywhere...

Can anyone see any problems with the query?

```
;with K as ( 
select cast(c.Code as int) code
from rmCategory c, rmCategoryGroup cg, rmIdentification ic
where 1=1
  and c.CategoryGroupID=cg.ID
  and c.ID=ic.ID0
)

select 
F.STAV_AKT [Code]
, count(F.STAV_AKT) [Count] 
, sum(F._IsInIntersection) [CountIntersection]

from
(
select 
    f.*
    , case when f.KVALIF IN (select code from K) and f.KVALIF is not null then 1 else 0 end _IsInIntersection
from frmFormData_208629_MaMo2_IMPORT f, rmIdentification i

where 1=1
    and f.ID=i.id0
    and i.isValid=1
    and f.sysDAVKA=5

) F

group by F.STAV_AKT
order by F.STAV_AKT
```

I also tried CASTing parameter inside of `sum(cast(F._IsInIntersection as int)) [CountIntersection]` to be sure to use int values instead of the boolean ones, but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin, I'm suspecting that `c.Code` also contains the value 'ADMIN' in the part

```
cast(c.Code as int) code
```

It runs good without the SUM because it's part of a CTE and is not materialized when the column is not used.

If for example I run the following code example in [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25427) it runs fine, but if I also select the column `Code` it fails when trying to CAST 'ADMIN' to INT ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25426)).

```
;WITH cte as
(
    select CAST(a AS INT) AS Code
            ,'Dummy' AS Column2
    FROM (
            SELECT 1 AS a
            UNION ALL SELECT 'a'
        ) t
)
SELECT Column2
    --,Code
FROM cte
```

So try to figure out what exactly the values for column `Code` are by using e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM rmCategory
```

Comment: The declared CTE - 'K' is not being used in the subsequent `SELECT` statement

Comment: Yes it is used in the subselect F inside the CASE expression: `select code from K`

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype of f.sysDAVKA?

Try running

```
SELECT f.sysDAVKA 
FROM frmFormData_208629_MaMo2_IMPORT f 
WHERE f.sysDAVKA = 'ADMIN'
```

My gut feeling is you will find at least one row. If this is true, then changing your `WHERE` clause to

```
where 1=1
    and f.ID=i.id0
    and i.isValid=1
    and f.sysDAVKA=CAST(5 AS char(1))
```

should resolve the problem.

Comment: sysDAVKA is "int" column